# sql запрос с условием

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день

Помогите сформировать запрос. Есть таблица `bill` (MySQL) в ней следующие поля:

- 1: id
- 2: id_importance
- 3: date_start

Надо выбрать все запись в определенном диапазоне по полю `date_start` (допустим +/- 7 дней), но если у записи `id_importance` равно 7, то выбираем их уже в другом диапазоне (допустим +/- 20 дней).

Всё это надо сделать в одном запросе. Возможно ли это?

Comment: Можно. используй `UNION` или `UNION ALL`.... то есть в целом запрос будет таким `(SELECT ... WHERE id_importance != 7) UNION (SELECT ...... WHERE id_importance = 7)`

Comment: спасибо за идею адаптировал в фремворке и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

> по полю date_start (допустим +/- 7 дней), но если у записи id_importance равно 7, то выбираем их уже в другом диапазоне (допустим +/- 20 дней).

```
WHERE date_start BETWEEN @date - INTERVAL CASE WHEN id_importance=7 THEN 20 ELSE 7 END DAY
                     AND @date + INTERVAL CASE WHEN id_importance=7 THEN 20 ELSE 7 END DAY
```